# Why were there no consequences for the Protagonist meeting his forward self?

Tags: tenet

The protagonist was advised that he should not come into contact with his forward self. But we can see him

> fighting with himself and Niel in the airport facility

and there are apparently no consequences for meeting his inverted self.

**How does this reconcile with the previous advice he received?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advice he gets is that he mustn't have any of his particles come into contact with ***the same particles going the other way through time*** or else those particles will explosively annihilate each other.

Note that when he

> [fights himself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWa0EGPgHrs)

he's wearing a different (full body) protective suit so that none of his particles come into direct contact.